# Accessing the `__proto__` property isn't getting what I would expect it to get Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

So, there's this code that I'm trying to make sense of:

```
function Mammal() {
  this.isMammal = 'yes';
}

function MammalSpecies(sMammalSpecies) {
  this.species = sMammalSpecies;
}

MammalSpecies.prototype = new Mammal();
MammalSpecies.prototype.constructor = MammalSpecies;

var oCat = new MammalSpecies('Felis');
console.log(oCat.isMammal); // 'yes'

function Animal() {
  this.breathing = 'yes';
}

var test = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(oCat))
console.log("Mark:1", test) /* output
{constructor: ƒ}
constructor: ƒ Mammal()
__proto__: Animal
breathing: "yes"
__proto__: Object*/
console.log("Mark:1.3", test.__proto__) /* output
{constructor: ƒ, __defineGetter__: ƒ, __defineSetter__: ƒ, hasOwnProperty: ƒ, __lookupGetter__: ƒ, …}
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
*/
console.log("Mark:2", Object.getPrototypeOf(test)) /* output
{constructor: ƒ, __defineGetter__: ƒ, __defineSetter__: ƒ, hasOwnProperty: ƒ, __lookupGetter__: ƒ, …}
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
(same as test.__proto__)
*/
```

```js
function Mammal() {
  this.isMammal = 'yes';
}

function MammalSpecies(sMammalSpecies) {
  this.species = sMammalSpecies;
}

MammalSpecies.prototype = new Mammal();
MammalSpecies.prototype.constructor = MammalSpecies;

var oCat = new MammalSpecies('Felis');
console.log(oCat.isMammal); // 'yes'

function Animal() {
  this.breathing = 'yes';
}

var test = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(oCat))
console.log("Mark:1", test)
/* output
{constructor: ƒ}
constructor: ƒ Mammal()
__proto__: Animal
breathing: "yes"
__proto__: Object*/
console.log("Mark:1.3", test.__proto__)
/* output
{constructor: ƒ, __defineGetter__: ƒ, __defineSetter__: ƒ, hasOwnProperty: ƒ, __lookupGetter__: ƒ, …}
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
*/
console.log("Mark:2", Object.getPrototypeOf(test))
/* output
{constructor: ƒ, __defineGetter__: ƒ, __defineSetter__: ƒ, hasOwnProperty: ƒ, __lookupGetter__: ƒ, …}
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
(same as test.__proto__)
*/
```

So, what I don't understand, is, I would expect `test.__proto__` to be equal to:

```
breathing: "yes"
__proto__: Object
```

Because the `__proto__` key of the `test` object is equal to that, as shown in the "Mark:1" log, right?  `Object.getProtoTypeOf(test)` logs the same. What am I missing?

Comment: `test` is not an `Animal`, so why should its `__proto__` be `Animal.prototype`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look into the next line.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(oCat))
```

`Object.getPrototypeOf(oCat)` is `new Mamal()`.

So we can say that `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(oCat))` is equal to `Object.getPrototypeOf(new Mamal())`  .

And `Object.getPrototypeOf(new Mamal())` is `Mamal` because `new Mamal()` return a new object with prototype `Mamal`.

So this is why you see `Mamal` when calls for `console.log("Mark:1", test)`.

Comment: Whoops! I actually omitted some code! Yeah, I had expected the prototypes to layout exactly how you just said, but my logs were indicating otherwise. Later down the road, I had some code that added the `Animal()` object to the prototype chain. I just forgot about the object mutability factor, and it was logging what oCat was later down the line, as opposed to the moment it was logged, which was confusing me, but I completely understand now, thanks for the answer!